# HMTL5 Website Overflow-x

Tags: css, html, mobile, media-queries, fluid-layout

I have recently put my "alpha" stage website live - http://www.elegantdesigns.comule.com/

I coded it fully with mobile support using media queries. When view in browser and making the width smaller, it works flawlessly. However when I use it on my mobile device (Samsung Galaxy Note 2) with a width of 720 pixels there is a space to the right of everything that is only populated by the pages background.

I have used widths of 100%, I have also set the overflow-x to hidden for multiple elements.

Take a look for yourself using the link above.

This is what the site looks like on my device.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/27wJc.png

Anyone have any ideas?

Here are the links to all stylesheets that control the main mobile parts of the website.
 - http://elegantdesigns.comule.com/mobilestyle.css
 - http://elegantdesigns.comule.com/tabstyle.css

Here is the html controlling the header:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flat Designs</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 811px)"href="mainstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 810px) and (min-width: 721px)" href="tabstyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 720px) and (min-width: 521px)" href="mobilestyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 520px) and (min-width: 431px)" href="tinystyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 430px) and (min-width: 1px)" href="smalleststyle.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.iconj.com/ico/9/e/9ecev208p2.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ropa+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit seems to be in how you've styled the elements in your footer. In this case, removing relative positioning along with the left property fixes the issue.

```
about {
  position: relative; /* You don't need this */
  left: 30%; /* Removing this property fixes the overflow/width issue */
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

You are using relative positioning for all elements in your footer, but with no apparent purpose. Using the `#about` element as an example; in order to achieve what you're achieve, you are better removing the *`relative` positioning*, along with the percentage *`left` value*, and simply setting the *`text-align` property* to *`center`*.

```
about {
  color: #666;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You should only use relative positioning if you wish to exert greater control over the positioning of an element, outside of the document flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot bud! I went through and removed them all until I narrowed it down to a few in the footer/content. I don't fully understand why this happens though? Is there a logical reason?

Comment: Ahh I found the issue thanks to your advice, it was also a problem with the way my nav bar was centered. I was using a desktop technique by making another div, and setting it to 50% from the left, while also setting the nav bar to -50% which effectively centered the whole thing.

Comment: Good stuff! Here's a great article on [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) on CSS positioning. It is a great resource for anyone doing front-end dev. You should never need to use positioning unless you want to pull an element out of the normal document flow. You should get to grips with positioning and learn the differences between `top: 50px` and `margin-top: 50px`, etc.